# How to generate weak topology by the family of semi-norm?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-algebras, amenability

How to generate a **weak topology** by the family of **semi-norm** $$ \{P_i \colon A \rightarrow  B, i \in I\} $$  in which $$ P_i(a)=\lVert ia\rVert+\lVert ai\rVert$$  when $A$ is a Banach algebra and $I$ is a closed ideal of $A$ and $a$ belongs to $A$.

Actually it is based on the definition of strict topology from the book:   **Volker Runde** - lectures on amenability- 2nd chapter Amenability Banach algebra.

Comment: By this, he (presumably) means the weakest topology on $A$ which makes the maps $P_i(a):=\lVert ia\rVert+\lVert ai\rVert$ ($i\in I$) continuous. Note that $B$ must be $[0,\infty)$ here. The *weak* topolgy on $A$ is the weakest topology on $A$ which makes the maps $a\mapsto f(a)$ continuous for each $f\in A'$ (the dual space of $A$). In other words, this is generated by the family of seminorms  $\{p_f(a)=\lvert f(a)\rvert:f \in A'\}$.

Comment: How this weak topology is generated by the family of seminorm?

Comment: This is a standard construction in general topology (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).